# Discord.js V14 Auto Mod, Reason(s) for deletion

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want my bot to give a reason for the users advertisement being deleted.

I want to make my bot send the reason or reasons that the users message was deleted for.

This is my whitelist or if someone doesn't have a link in their message as my server is an advertising server it gets deleted and sent into a logs channel.

```
// Whitelist
const stickyChannels = [`1062515771319799908`, `1062515773605691513`, `1062515781893636096`, '1081339855004520589']
const whitelist = ['discord.gg/', 'https', '.gg/']
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
  if (stickyChannels.includes(message.channel.id)) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let foundInText = false;
    for (var i in whitelist) {
      if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(whitelist[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
    }

    if (foundInText) { return } else {
      message.delete()
      let warn = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`Invalid Invite`)
        .setDescription(`Your advert has been deleted due to it not containing a discord invite link!`)
        .setColor(`#ff8cb7`)
        .setFooter({ text: "Protected by " + client.user.username })
      message.channel.send({ content: `<@${message.author.id}>`, embeds: [warn] }).then(msg => {
        setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000)

        let logs = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle(`Auto Moderation`)
          .setColor(`#ff8cb7`)
          .addFields(
            { name: `**Target**`, value: `\`${message.author.tag}\``, inline: true },
            { name: `**Advertisement Channel**`, value: `\`#${message.channel.name}\``, inline: true },
            { name: `**Target Advertisement**`, value: `\`\`\`${message.content}\`\`\``, inline: false },
            { name: `**Reason(s) For Deletion**`, value: `\`\`\`Advertisement Content | Does Not Contain A Link\`\`\``, inline: false }
          )

        client.channels.cache.get(`1083470204027293797`).send({ embeds: [logs] })
      })
    }
  }
});
```

There is a lot going on in there but just like the `foundInText` I want a `reason4Deletion` and in the fields for Reason(s) I want to add `${reason4Deletion}` that will join all the reasons with `.join("\\n")`  if there is a way to have the backlisted words have a different value such as:

```
const backlist = [  
{ name: "discord.gg/", value: `Advertisement contains links`},  
{ name: "@everyone" +  "@here",  value: "Advertisement contains pings"}  
]
```

And then it uses the name as the word filter and then value as the reason.

Answer (score 0):

## This is an improved version of the code you provided.

You must **await** for the author message to be deleted before sending a warning message. In your case, the **message.delete** function is executed after the warn message is sent.

[+] Whitelist & Blacklist & No Ping + Simple

```js
const stickyChannels = [
    '1062515771319799908',
    '1062515773605691513',
    '1062515781893636096',
    '1081339855004520589'
];
const whitelist = [
    'discord.gg/',
    'discord.com/invite/',
    'discordapp.com/invite/',
    '.gg/'
];
const blacklist = [
    'free nitro'
];
const ping = [
    '<@',
    '@everyone',
    '@here'
];
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (stickyChannels.includes(message.channel.id)) {
        async function warn(reason) {
            await message.delete().then(async () => {
                await message.channel.send({
                    content: `<@!${message.author.id}>`,
                    embeds: [{
                        title: 'AutoMod',
                        description: reason,
                        color: '#ff8cb7',
                        footer: {
                            text: 'Protected by ' + client.user.username
                        }
                    }]
                }).then((x) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        x.delete().catch(e => console.log(e))
                    }, 10000);
                });
                await client.channels.cache.get('1083470204027293797').send({
                    embeds: [{
                        title: 'Auto Moderation',
                        fields: [{
                                name: `**Target**`,
                                value: `\`${message.author.tag}\``,
                                inline: true
                            },
                            {
                                name: `**Advertisement Channel**`,
                                value: `\`#${message.channel.name}\``,
                                inline: true
                            },
                            {
                                name: `**Target Advertisement**`,
                                value: `\`\`\`${message.content.slice(0, 1000)}\`\`\``,
                                inline: false
                            },
                            {
                                name: `**Reason(s) For Deletion**`,
                                value: `\`\`\`${reason.replace('Your advert has been removed because it', 'Advert')}\`\`\``,
                                inline: false
                            }
                        ],
                        color: '#ff8cb7'
                    }]
                });
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
        };
        if (ping.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) || message.mentions.members.first()) {
            warn('Your advert has been removed because it contained a ping!');
        } else if (blacklist.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
            warn('Your advert has been removed because it contains a banned word!');
        } else if (!whitelist.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
            warn('Your advert has been removed because it didn\'t contain a valid discord invite!');
        };
    }
});
```